# Posting to FB/Twitter - addon suggestion?

Tags: add-on, facebook

I want each channel entry to be posted to FB and Twitter. I'm looking at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/social-update. Does anyone have experience with this? Documentation for this addon is a lacking, IMHO.

Or alternative suggestions?

Comment: Can you expand on what exactly your requirements are? Better yet, try that plugin and post here if you run into any specific shortcomings and are looking for an alternative (there is always Devot:ee 30 day refund policy). Simply asking "does anyone have any experience" will lead to endless answers and no real solution.

Comment: Requirements is just that each entry is FB-posted/tweeted. Maybe I'll go give the addon a try. Just didn't want to waste my time in case someone else has a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for Social Update can be found [here](http://www.intoeetive.com/docs/social_update.html)

The update is sent to one or several social accounts you've pre-authorized in Control Panel. The text of update needs to be entered for each entry using custom field.

If you're rather looking for solution that will post to user's timeline, consider [Social Login Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/social-login-pro)

As  Adrian suggested, it's better to try, and request moneyback if you find out it does not do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck posting to Facebook and Twitter using dlvr.it.

I set up recipes to take the information from my RSS feed and post the title/story/link to both Twitter and Facebook.

I speed up the turnaround using Superfeeder's pubsubhubbub service.